# ProgressBar change while opening PDF file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have simple app that opens PDF files from folder. I want to add progress bar while the pdf is opening.

for now i have this in my code:

```
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            statusProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

It changes the while the pdf opens but only on given time. I want to show the progress of the opening precisely with 100% when it opens but I can't find anywhere how to do it.

I'm opening the file with this simple code:

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path + selectedFile);
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: how do you open pdf file? can you provide some sample code for that?

Comment: If you load it with a Stream, you can read a buffer and report progress every `1/100` chunk of data loaded. EDIT: `Process.Start()`? You're not loading a PDF file, you're executing the associated application! Show a marquee instead. See `Process.WaitForInputIdle`.

Comment: You have no idea whatsoever how long it is going to take.  It will be correct as often as a clock that doesn't tick, twice a day, if you're lucky.  Set the progressbar's Style property to Marquee.